# $(MSBuildStartupDirectory) in Visual Studio points to different places on different machines

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

In a large solution, I'm integrating Gendarme into Visual Studio 2008 compilation process. I am using [GendarmeMsBuild](https://github.com/unintelligible/GendarmeMsBuild) task along with a `.targets` file to add a `AfterBuild` target to every project in the solution. I am looking for a way to import this file into `.csproj` files in a way that wouldn't require me to change the include path (the projects have different nesting levels). Apart from using NuGet `SolutionDir` variable, best way to solve this seemed to be to use [`$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). However, as it turns out, on some machines, using the same version of VS 2008 (as same updates installed, as far as I was able to check) this resolves to the solution directory, and on others to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`.

How can I either

- get this to always resolve to the solution folder
- or obtain the base folder in another consistent way?

Comment: Need some more information on what you mean by 'load' and why. Is this a compile time issue or a run time issue?

Comment: It is the directory that msbuild was started from.  Common7\IDE when it was started from the IDE and the default working directory for devenv.exe was never changed, basically anywhere but usually the solution directory when it was started from the command line.

Comment: @HansPassant: that's it! I've just checked: when I start VS by clicking on the solution file, MSBuildStartupDirectory is set to the location of `.sln`, but when I start it from Start Menu it's set to `Program Files\...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SolutionDir` is not exclusive to NuGet, NuGet simply adds the definition in case the project file is being built directly. If the build was started from a solution file then `SolutionDir` will be defined by MSBuild.